# Informix database connection using .net core giving Protocol specific error code(s) error

Tags: c#, .net-core, db2, informix

I am trying to connect to an Informix database in .NET Core 3.1 using IBM.Data.DB2.Core NuGet package.
I am getting the error:

```
IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Exception (0x80004005): ERROR [08001] [IBM] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS". 
Location where the error was detected: "10.2.4.25".  Communication function detecting the error: "recv".  Protocol specific error ode(s): "*", "*", "0".  SQLSTATE=08001

   at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2ConnPool.Open(DB2Connection connection, String& szConnectionString, DB2ConnSettings& ppSettings, Object& ppConn)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Connection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.NoopExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

What do I need to do to fix the problem(s)?

Comment: Are you connecting to a DRDA listener or a SQLI one? 
The "IBM.Data.DB2.Core" .NET provider uses the DRDA protocol to connect to Informix. 
Other Informix APIs (like Informix .NET,  .NET Core or ODBC) use the "native" SQLI protocol which is the default one. 
Check if your Informix instance is configured for DRDA clients (https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?49253,Enabling+DRDA+on+Informix)

Comment: We probably need some more information.  There are several things that could be relevant.  Presumably the platform is a version of Windows (but which one)?  What is the version of Informix to which you're trying to connect?  Is it configured to listen for DRDA connections?  What connection string are you using?